# Crashlooperror in Google Cloud Shell

Tags: google-api, google-kubernetes-engine

I am taking a course in google cloud on launching a kubernetes engine cluster. I received this when running through twice.

What is the fix for CrashLoopBackOff? I have not been able to locate.

```
(venv) student_04_9b8cb56b5006@cloudshell:~/cloud-vision/python/awwvision/cloud-vision/python/awwvision (qwiklabs-gcp-00-128898864713)$ kubectl get pods
W0619 19:58:53.278025    3544 gcp.go:120] WARNING: the gcp auth plugin is deprecated in v1.22+, unavailable in v1.25+; use gcloud instead.
To learn more, consult https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
NAME                                READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
awwvision-webapp-55f5dbb8c7-mdtnq   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (2m45s ago)   24m
awwvision-worker-79c846b86d-f9mvp   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (2m4s ago)    23m
awwvision-worker-79c846b86d-lhnt8   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (2m25s ago)   23m
awwvision-worker-79c846b86d-t79zc   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9 (2m45s ago)   23m
redis-master-6c59fc54c-ldk8t        1/1     Running            0               25m
```

Comment: You provide very little relevant information beyond the error. It's helpful to provide relevant, additional information when you seek help. For example, which course? (URL?), what is the Deployment that you ran that caused the error?

Comment: The error often (!?) results when the image defined in a Deployment is incorrect or inaccessible. The image can be inaccessible between the it doesn't exist. It would be helpful for you to additionally include the result of e.g. `kubectl describe pod/awwvision-webapp-55f5dbb8c7-mdtnq`  and/or one of the works e.g. `kubectl describe pod/awwvision-worker-79c846b86d-lhnt8` in the question.

Comment: Proving the tutorial that you are using in your post can also help us identify the issue. Also, please add the versions of the services that you are using. As a first level troubleshooting step, try upgrading your nodepool version if it is not the latest one.